# [Android]How to set the current location to a location object on click of a button?

Tags: android, onclick, gps, location

I am trying to set the current location to an object on the click of a button. But I am getting an ANR error, when I click the button. This is the onClick method of the button I am talking about, where destinationObj is declared global and is of type Location. Please help me out.

```
 public void onClick(View v){

    double lat, lon;
    lat=destinationObj.getLatitude();
    lon=destinationObj.getLongitude();
    destinationObj.setLatitude(lat);
    destinationObj.setLongitude(lon);


}
```

and the logcat:

> 09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    ... 11 more
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    at com.example.user.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:130)
>   09-29 10:44:02.456: E/AndroidRuntime(14449):    ... 14 more
>   09-29 10:44:04.088: I/Process(14449): Sending signal. PID: 14449 SIG: 9

Comment: what is destinationObj? give complete implementation of ur code....

Comment: Have you resolved this: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: Nope. Still getting an error.

Comment: @anilkumar: destinationObj is an object of the class Location. Declared globally.

Answer (score 0):

destinationObj.setLatitude(destinationObj.getLatitude()); this makes no sense?

destinationObj being the same object for both the setter and getter. The left hand side should be a TextView or whatever you want to tell the current location.

if your setLatitude is implemented like:

```
this.latitude = getLatitude();
```

The code will enter a loop, continuously setting the latitude variable.

**Please try and follow this guide:** 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

In the guide do the following:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if ((this.location = location) == null)
        return;
}
```

Then on your instance of GPSTracker, lets call it, gps, call:

```
gps.getLatitude();
gps.getLongitude();
```

To get the latest received location from the GPS (notice will read the same values until the gps unit has settled)

If you really need a Location object then you can implement a getter yourself:

```
public class GPSTracker ...
...
   public Location getLastLocation() {
       return this.location;
   }
}
```

Comment: I agree that it gets into a loop and it was a silly mistake. But The left hand side can only be an object of location. But modifying the code as above is not helping either. the getter and setter are different now though. Please check the updated code and help me if you could.

Comment: I still think you are approaching this incorrectly. please follow the guide I added to the answer.

Comment: It didn't really help. How can you assign a value to an object of the class Location?

Comment: Added details to the answer